# How to call another python file, run it, and replace main.py with the new .py file?

Tags: python, exec

There are answers to questions like:

> How to run a py file from another py file?

But no answers have told how to replace main.py with the recently-ran file, but still jeep main.py.
I'm using python 3, and my execute command is this:

`exec(open('newfile.py').read())`

How can I replace main.py with newfile.py, but keep main.py?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I'm not clear for your Question but I just try to created first.py like this:

first.py

```
print('Hello world')
```

and then make second.py like this:

second.py

```
import os
os.system('python first.py')
```

and when you want to run on CLI you can type this command
[image]
this my environment in today's folder:
today folder:[image]

If not your work or clear for your Question feel free to asking more.

Comment: Adding to that, subprocess module of python provides more variety of functionality for these kinds of tasks in place of os.system. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements

Comment: @TH_SPT Hello! Thanks for your answer, but I'm running a Discord bot, and other users can't exactly type in a command in the command line when they are on Discord. Hope this makes sense, and again, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @discord.py_fanboy welcome bro. you can let's me know more about your discord It'll be the good practice for me about discord_bot. Can you invite me to join your discord and look and learn about it. I just rookie for programming so I wanna try to solve more. Feel free to give me question.

Answer (score 0):

I just try to created first.py like this:

```py
print('hello world!')
```

And second.py like this:

```py
import first
```

Then first.py will run in the Python environment that second.py run.
But in first.py `__name__` value will be `'first'` and not `'__main__'`